# Auto scroll image inside element from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation, gsap

I have long image that i want to display it inside a div element that has specific dimensions. The image inside is in absolute position.

The image has a "Start" and "Finish" text inside so i can check if the scrolling is done.

Here is the code that i have tried to move the image up so i can see the whole image while it's scrolling.

```
TweenLite.to($(".pa-video-container-mobile img"), 20, {transform: "translate3d(0,100vh,0)", yPercent: -100});
```

I have created a jsfiddle. Try to hit the "Run" button more than 2 times. Sometimes the code works.

https://jsfiddle.net/0xu476vp/1/

I have tried to transform the image through tweenlite library but the code does not show the bottom of the image.

Sometimes the image is shown near the end (without showing the "Finish" text) and sometimes the image is far away from the "Finish" text.

Comment: Hi NetDevPlanet and welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your JSFiddle doesn't appear to be working for me. What are you trying to achieve ? Why not have it scroll in a classic container using `overflow-y: visible` ?

Comment: Hi @jake i forgot to hit the save button for my jsfiddle. I have updated the link for jsfiddle. Try to hit the Run button more than 2 times. Sometimes the code works.

Comment: You're aware you could use a CSS animation for that instead of JavaScript ? Do you need to know when the scrolling is done ? Your JSFiddle works fine now, what would be the problem then ?

Comment: I need it in javascript because i want to change the speed dynamically and make a reverse animation. As i said before the code sometimes works fine but sometimes the animation stops before the end of the image and other times in the middle. Maybe the problem is with the image, the dom does not check the entire height of the image. I can do the animation by entering the height of the image but i want to check if i can do this without entering the height.

Comment: What browser are you using ? I've tried it multiple times and it works flawlessly.